# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'typecode'

Tags: python, vsphere, pysphere

I am trying to use VIProperty in pysphere but I am getting **'str' object has no attribute 'typecode'**.

Code:

```
for h, mor in server.get_hosts().items():
    if mor == 'xxx.com':
        prop = VIProperty(server, mor)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "teardown.py", line 29, in <module>
    prop = VIProperty(server, mor)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pysphere/vi_property.py", line 38, in __init__
    self._type = obj.typecode.type[1]
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'typecode'
```

Answer (score -1):

works currect because "mor" stil string type and **'str' object has no attribute 'typecode'**.

[VIProperty](https://github.com/itnihao/pysphere/blob/master/pysphere/vi_property.py):

```
class VIProperty(object):
    def __init__(self, server, obj):
        self._server = server
        self._obj = obj
        self._values_set = False
        self._type = obj.typecode.type[1]
```

your call method:

```
for h, mor in server.get_hosts().items():
    if mor == 'xxx.com':
        print type(mor) # <<<< 'str'
        prop = VIProperty(server, mor)
```

try that:

```
    hosts = server.get_hosts()
    for hmor, hname in hosts.items():
        if hname == 'xxx.com':
           p = VIProperty(server, hmor)
```